# Simplification of an Equation with Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm reading through examples on [this site](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs504/s00m/notes/recurrence/solve/step2/step2.html).
In example 2_2, given the recurrence relation $A_n - 2A_{n-1} = 2n^2$, the guess for the particular solution is $A_n= Bn^2 + Cn + D$. Substituting that into the recurrence relation gets you [image]

I just don't know how to continue this to get the answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the equation you got by substituting in to the recurrence relation to be true for all $n$, so $B - 2B - 2$, $C + 4B - 2C$ and $D - 2B + 2 C - 2D$ must all be $0$.  Now, what are $B$, $C$ and $D$?

Comment: Will the terms always equal to zero regardless of the coefficient in front of the $n^2$?

Comment: And why can't I just equate coefficients?

Comment: @Extreme112 It is equating coefficients.  On the one hand you have $$Mn^2 + Nn + P = Qn^2 + Rn + S$$ to get $$\begin{cases} M = Q \\ N=R \\ P = S \end{cases}$$ and on the other hand you have $$Xn^2 + Yn + Z = 0$$ to get $$\begin{cases} X = 0 \\ Y=0 \\ Z = 0 \end{cases}$$ ...it's just two different ways of looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Israel pointed out, the following is obtained. 
Let $f_{n} = a n^{2} + b n + c$ in the difference equation $f_{n} = 2 f_{n-1} + 2 n^{2}$. 
\begin{align}
a n^{2} + b n + c &= 2 a (n-1)^{2} + 2b (n-1) + 2c + 2 n^{2} \\
&= 2a n^{2} - 4b n + 2a + 2b n - 2b + 2 n^{2} \\
&= 2(a+1) n^{2} + (b-2a) n + (a-b+c).
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
(a + 2) n^{2} + (b-4a) n + (2a - 2b + c) = 0.
\end{align}
Equating coefficients leads to $a = -2$, $b= 4a = -8$, and $c = 2b -2a = -12$ for which
\begin{align}
f_{n} = -2( n^{2} + 4n + 6) 
\end{align}